# Spring Batch : Display the error line number of a loading failed

Tags: spring-batch

I'd like to display the error line number of a file when a loading fails.
(sometimes I use lineMapper. For others loadings, I use fieldSetMapper)

Some people sais to use `#{fileReader.currentItemCount}`
or to redifine LineMapper but I don't understand how to use it.

Do you have somes examples ?

Regards.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle exception and skip the wrong csv line as well?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53347349/how-to-handle-exception-and-skip-the-wrong-csv-line-as-well)

Comment: It's not helpful for me because I don't want to skip the error lines.
I tried to add in my job an @OnReadError method like in your example but it doesn't work.... Any idea ?

Comment: If the line cannot be parsed or mapped to an object, you would have to skip it anyway, correct? Otherwise what would your mapper return? So in my opinion a `SkipListener` is the the way to for this use case.